# Centos 7 - sshd sftp group permissions messed up after update

Tags: permissions, centos, updates, sftp

`Centos` recently updated to `7.3` and there's been problems with sshd sftp group permissions. I have one user that is chrooted to it's home directory, and that user is in group `sftponly`. Then i have the /var/www directory, which has `775` permissions and owner is `apache` and owner group is `sftponly`. I have a bind link pointing from `/home/user/files/web` --> `/var/www`, so the user can access /var/www even though being chrooted to it's home directory. I can view files in /var/www with that user, but impossible to edit or add anything. This worked fine before the big `Centos` `7.3` update, and now it's stopped working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1398569) and it will be fixed in the next update. Before that, it is good to stay on the previous version.

Comment: Approximately when is the fix coming?